# SQL-query to find similar fields

Tags: sql

In SQL, I have a table which have fields `a_1,a_2,..., a_10`. What kind of query says if I have rows `s,t` such that `s.a_1=t.a_1 ,..., s.a_6=t.a_6` and for some `j>6` we have `s.a_i<>t.a_i`?

Comment: Perhaps it will be clearer if you give a specific example. Are you asking how you can (e.g.) find rows which have equal values for at least 6 out of 10 columns?

Comment: Sorry. I'm just a mathematician who turned to be a programmer. :)

Comment: What does "j" represent?

Comment: It is some integer so I have to find those rows having correspondence between first six a_i:s such that the rows are not identical.

Comment: What data type are the a_1, a_2 fields?

Comment: a_1 is a date and a_2 is a varchar. The others are dates, integers or varchars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join table to itself on the condition you supplied. Like:

```
select
   a.ID 
from 
  table as a join table as b 
  on a.a_1 = b.a_1 and ... and a.a_j <> b.a_j
```

Comment: +1 The question says "some j" though so I suppose there would need to be a load of `or`-ed conditions for the columns from `j-n`

Comment: Do I have to write several cases: on (a.a_1 = b.a_1 and ... and a.a_7 <> b.a_7) or (a.a_1 = b.a_1 and ... and a.a_8 <> b.a_8) or (a.a_1 = b.a_1 and ... and a.a_9 <> b.a_9) or (a.a_1 = b.a_1 and ... and a.a_10 <> b.a_10)?

Comment: No. `on (a.a_1 = b.a_1 and ... a.a_6 = b.a_6) and (a.a_7 <> b.a_7 or a.a_8 <> b.a_8 or a.a_9 <> b.a_9 or a.a_10 <> b.a_10` if I understand the requirement correctly.